# Working in and out of classes and functions

Tags: python, class

Quick question... I've been working on a little program that will calculate the final grade percentage based on 'Homework', 'Quizzes', and 'Tests' along with the earned letter grade. This is a program that I'm testing out new things with, and I was wondering how I could use all of this with or within a class?

I've thought about keeping the functional stuff as is, and just using a class to basically print out a nice string of the name of the student, the final letter grade, and percentage. I'm having trouble bringing in the outside data even for the simple print out within the class. Any ideas?

Also, is there anyway to let user's input create brand new empty dictionaries? (Maybe if multiple dictionaries could be created, I could make a function or method to calculate the class average)
I appreciate your help.
Thanks!

```
student1 = {}
student = [student1]
def maker_d():
    name = raw_input("Please enter the student's name: ")
    student1['Name'] = name
    homework = raw_input("Please enter all of the student's homework grades separated by     a space: ")
    homework = [float(i) for i in homework.split()]
    student1['homework']= homework
    quizzes = raw_input("Please enter all of the student's quiz scores separated by a space: ")
    quizzes = [float(i) for i in quizzes.split()]
    student1['quizzes'] = quizzes
    tests = raw_input("Please enter all of the student's test scores separated by a space: ")
    tests = [float(i) for i in tests.split()]
    student1['tests'] = tests


def average(student):
    return sum(student) / len(student)

def get_average(student):
    h = average(student['homework'])
    q = average(student['quizzes'])
    t = average(student['tests'])
    total_average = (h * 0.1) + (q * 0.3) + (t * 0.6) #designates homework as 10%, quizzes as 30% and tests as 60% of final grade average
    return total_average


def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif 80<= score <90:
        return "B"
    elif 70 <= score < 80:
        return "C"
    elif 60 <= score < 70:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"


def get_class_average(student):
    total = 0
    for each in student:
        total += get_average(each)
    return total / len(student)
    return get_class_average(get_average[student])

    class FinalGradePrinter(object):


        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name
        def __str__(self,name):
            print "% ',' your final grade is a %s based on your overall percentage of %f" % (self.name) 



def main():
    maker_d()
    print get_class_average(student)
    print get_letter_grade(get_class_average(student))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are templates for objects that you want to use in an application, and objects are intended to encapsulate 'things' by encapsulating the attributes for that 'thing', and also functions that work with those attributes (e.g. calculate values based on the attribute values, change them etc). This topic is far too involved to give more of an introduction here,  would be worth doing some research into Object-Oriented programming.

In your case, you definitely have a case for having `Student` as a class, this is a 'thing' in your code which has attributes, and also functions that work with those attributes. Below is a good starting point for you to create your own Student class - it would be a good exercise to try and fill in the class and modify your code to use it (which will require learning about Object-Oriented programming). As you grow the example, you may want to create classes for quizzes, tests and homework as well.

```
class Student:

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, name, homework, quizzes, tests):
        self.name = name
        self.homework = homework
        self.quizzes = quizzes
        self.tests = tests

    # Function to return average for this student
    def get_average(self):
        h = average(self.homework)
        ...
        return total_average
```

Good luck and have fun!